# Eclipse: can I keep progress dialog from blocking UI somehow?

Tags: eclipse

When Eclipse builds, as it sometimes decides to do, sometimes it pops up a dialog that totally blocks the use of the project window, so one can't do any work, and often one can't stop the build, sometimes for minutes. Is there any way of preventing the blocking of the UI?

I am using 2018-12, but this has been the behavior of every Eclipse I've ever used, I think.

I have the 'Always run in background' checkbox checked; I don't know what that does for builds. It's tooltip says 'run long-running operations in the background when possible'. When is building in the background not possible?

Comment: Building what language? The Java build doesn't normally do this.

Comment: @greg-449 Java; and I think you're right, under normal conditions. And I think I've got this problem sorted, actually, not solving the stated problem, but now my builds have stopped acting up. For some old experiment, I had some items in the .classpath pointing waywards, to some jars outside of the project. Not a good thing in itself...

Comment: Well, Eclipse's acting up again. Complete rebuilds for no apparent reason. With the modal pop-up blocking the UI. F.